# Load Defaults, Allow Modification

Tags: forms, gui-design, wpf

My form confirms components for a product prior to assembly. Each field is pre-loaded from the spec for that product. Occasionally, the user overrides the spec with a known item or custom item.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fi561r.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

**Question:**

Does my design have any obvious flaws?  If so, please describe.

**Notes:**

- The `Value` initializes from the spec.
- The last `Value` is `(Custom)` to require a `Custom` entry. The user must actively look through the list before resorting to a `Custom` value.
- A highlighted row indicates the property has been overridden.

**Also considered:**

- Displaying `SpecValue` - for reference without resetting
- Editable dropdown - more compact

P.S. I have no formal design training, and I tend to overthink design, getting stuck not knowing what is best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Color**

The color difference between first and second line is not enough. You should never use only color to transmit information because lot of people are one kind of color blind [Wikipedia color blind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_blindness).

Lot of design choice on color apply to bad reading condition think mobile, sunny area...

It's better to have extra text, really simple icon, even a star on the line, or something at least color blind proof like strong text.

**Columns**

- You could merge Value and Custom columns. The important information is Default or Customized. So you could have only one combobox with Rubber Mallet (default), FiberGlass(option), Wood(option), Paper(option), R&D Polymer #5(User defined)
- Another option if to make one column with information Default, Option, User specified. And the other column always displayed the name, and make it editable only for customized by user.

  - Column Type one of the 3 value (Default, Option, User specified) or 2 option (Default,Custom)
  - Column Value one of (Rubber Mallet,FiberGlass,Wood,Paper,R&D Polymer #5...) This column should be editable only if user defined/custom is set.

**Filling vs reading**

Maybe you should provide an interface dedicated to enter information, and a really reduced one only to display the choices. If user don't need the information all the times remove it, and provide a way for exceptional case to access the edition form.

**Ask yourself questions on everything**

Is it absolutely the best option to edit inside grid or a popup menu with more space to provide options like the more commons options or the 5 last customized...

Comment: Great suggestions! Clarification please: **Columns** Please elaborate. The first seems to contradict itself: could merge... could split. The second is confusing. Is the "one column" a dropdown with the following items: <DefaultValue>, <AltValue-1>, <AltValue-2>, ... <AltValue-n>, "User Specified" and the "other column" a textbox with the text value (and only editable for "User Specified"? **Filling vs reading** A parent interface has the values better laid out. An "Override" button will bring up this exceptional case interface.

Comment: @Steven did some edits hope it's better